# How to delete multiple rows from json file using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I do have the following sample JSON file

```
 [
  {
    "name": "A"
    "email": "A@test.com",
    "admin": false,
    "groupAdmin": false,
    "profileUpdatable": true
  },
  {"name": "B"
    "email": "B@test.com",
    "admin": false,
    "groupAdmin": false,
    "profileUpdatable": true
  },
  {"name": "C"
    "email": "C@test.com",
    "admin": false,
    "groupAdmin": false,
    "profileUpdatable": true
  },
  {"name": "A"
    "admin": false,
    "groupAdmin": false,
    "profileUpdatable": true
  }
]
```

I want to do the following using python3:

- Want to delete the block which doesn't have the key "email".
- Want to extract only email value

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only want to extract the email values then you don't need to delete that blocks which don't have  email key

Answer (score 2):

You don´t have to remove the blocks. Iterate over the persons and take the email key if present.

By the way, you have an error in your file. After the value for name, a comma is missing in each object.

```
data =  [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "email": "A@test.com",
    "admin": False,
    "groupAdmin": False,
    "profileUpdatable": True
  },
  {"name": "B",
    "email": "B@test.com",
    "admin": False,
    "groupAdmin": False,
    "profileUpdatable": True
  },
  {"name": "C",
    "email": "C@test.com",
    "admin": False,
    "groupAdmin": False,
    "profileUpdatable": True
  },
  {"name": "A",
    "admin": False,
    "groupAdmin": False,
    "profileUpdatable": True
  }
]

def get_emails(data: list):
    e_mails = []
    for person in data:
        if "email" in person:
            e_mails.append(person["email"])
    return e_mails

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_emails(data=data))
```